# Connecting remote database server in Rails app failed

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, firewall

Using Rails 3.2, mysql2 gem, MariaDB 5.5. I got the following error while trying to deploy the app for the first time:

`Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'abc'@'%' to database 'app_production'`

I'm not sure why the percent sign `%` in `'abc'@'%'`.

Here's my `database.yml`:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: true
  host: db.domain.com
  port: 3306
  database: app_production
  pool: 5
  username: abc
  password: some_password_here
  socket: /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

My `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` has `bind 0.0.0.0`, firewall is temporarily disabled with `sudo iptables -F`.

Comment: `%` is a wildcard.  There's more about this in [MySQL Error 1045, “Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)”)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989030/mysql-error-1045-access-denied-for-user-userlocalhost-using-password-ye#15989067) and [Allowing wildcard (%) access on MySQL db, getting error “access denied for '<user>'@'localhost'”](http://serverfault.com/questions/122472/allowing-wildcard-access-on-mysql-db-getting-error-access-denied-for-use#122710).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error due to permission on database access for the user, so you have to grant access permission for this user on above database. Find below command to grant permission. run these command on mysql terminal

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON app_production.* TO 'abc'@'%'  WITH GRANT OPTION
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

Comment: Thanks. I replace the wildcard `%` with `ip_address` instead.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like the user `abc` is not set up with MySQL.  Go to your MySQL client and make sure that user is created (with that database).