# Error while trying to connect to the database server: [1045] Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, ssl

I have a MySQL database running and I created a new user called 'ssluser' with SSL REQUIRED. I'm having trouble with this user logging in from a client to a remote server.

I verified the firewall is not an issue. iptables are not reporting dropped packets.

I am able to connect from nonssluser to the remote server without an issue.

On the server my.cnf I have the CA, Cert, and Key file in place and MySQL WorkBench shows that SSL is enabled.

On the client, I have CA, Cert, and Key file in place as well.

For both certificates I used the FQDN as the common name. I'm not sure if that is the issue or not. Any ideas?

The connection is on a private network in the Digital Ocean datacenter NYC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[1045] Access denied for user
```

is a MySQL thing - which means that you are connecting - SSL does not seem to be the problem.

This most likely means you are authenticating wrong (have the wrong password).

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989030/mysql-error-1045-access-denied-for-user-userlocalhost-using-password-ye) to see if it helps if you are sure you have the right password.

Comment: So I'm able to connect from one linux server to the other now with the password being corrected. However, my application still fails.

Comment: @user1052448 does the user in application configuration has the `remote` privilege ?

Comment: the application doesn't support SSL connections :/

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question:

1 - The password was incorrect

and

2 - The application does not support SSL MySQL connections